# How and when to bind a dropdownlist properly in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, dropdown

I use the following method for binding dropdownlists in Angular, but I think I make something wrong as I do not get the expected behaviour sometimes:

***demoService.ts***

```
getProducts(): Observable<ProductDto> { ... }
```

***product.component.ts:***

```
products: ProductDto[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bindProducts();
}

bindProducts() {
    this.demoService.getProducts()
    .subscribe((list: ProductDto) => {
        this.products = list;
    });
    //for testing purpose
    const check = this.products;
}

test() {
    this.bindProducts();
    //for testing purpose
    const test= this.products;
}
```

**1.** Is the list variable definition `products: ProductDto[] = [];` is correct? Or should I use some Observable parameter for that?

**2.** Should I populate the dropdownlists in `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInit()`? in order to loading forms faster?

**3.** In the code above, I use `subscribe` method, but when binding list, I cannot make `this.products` to be filled in the `test()` method above. I think it is most probably subscribe method, but how can I make this variable to be filled later instead of onInit()? Should I use `toPromise` or something etc? What is the proper way?

Comment: Simply put, the function you hand to the `subscribe` method isn't immediately called but execution doesn't stop there. Your checks will always show `[]` because of this. Instead, put any logic that requires `this.products` inside of the callback

Comment: @MikeS. Any example for your explanations please? Sorry, I am new in Angular and would be appreciated if you post an example and give your ideas about the other points.

Comment: Sure, [here you go](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhhC8EDsCuxgG4BQBjA9ggzpAGZIJZwQAUAlHAHzQUBEAEiKjhAOo4BOwAEyYRMuAjlAA6YDgDmlKLQD0SiAICW+AA7AoAT3yIUwCACMQWKEnwgIJMhADuUQwhyQ94CJdQgBGeywaUTx8CRBpOQVlVQ1tXQMIVnYZbj5BJgwgA)

Comment: I look at, but I already called `this.bindProducts()` in my test() method. I do not understand the point you meant :(

Comment: You are passing a function to the `subscribe` function, but that function you're passing isn't immediately called, which means `this.products` is still `[]` when you assign your test variables. You could say it's async, but it doesn't nescessairly have to be (as shown in the playground snippet)

Comment: Ok, what is the solution to retrieve the full list from my Observable service method and use these list? I just simply get the data from an Observable method and use this data. It should not be too hard I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'proper' way just 'better' way 'recommended' way and 'preferential' way.

Below is how I would approach it

**product.component.ts:**

```typescript
export ProductComponent {
  products$ = this.demoService.getProducts();
}
```

Yes, I have removed `OnInit` life cycle hook and all other codes. I even have not declared the type of `products$` as `typescript` will infer this.

In my component I can then use `async` pipe

```html
<ng-container *ngIf='products$ | async as products'>
  <!-- My code here -->
</ng-container>
```

Basically we allow angular do the heavy lifting stuff like subscribing and unsubscribing for us.

You can have a look at [this sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-frost-3zicw?file=/src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thansk, but I also tried something similar to that (`products$ = this.demoService.getProducts();`) but I cannot get the product values in products$ variable. It is due to Observable maybe, but how can I get the values in it? I look at by debugger, but there are only some properties that does not help me to get the values. I need to get these values at first.

Comment: Have you included this line `*ngIf='products$ | async as products'` ?

Comment: Sorry, but I have to fix it without changing the current structure too much. So, I simply need to get product values after form loaded, but with the methods above that I used, I cannot. Is there any solution by using a proper method? Why is it too hard to get some data and set variable in Angular?

Comment: I have added a demo, hope it sheds some light of where you may be going wrong

Comment: What about the idea on question 2?